# How to check mysql queries was successful in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

I need to set traction for all mysql queries in shell script, so I have to find all queries are successfullt executed or not, so my simple code is below. here I have to find all mysql queries are done successfully or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
 set -x
 date=$(date +"%Y")
 month=$(date +"%m")
 day=$(date +"%d")
 user="appuser"
 password="Appuser"
 mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
 db="finance"
 tbname="cash_expense"
 $mysql -u$user -p$password -S"/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" $db -N -e"create table new like $tbname;rename table $tbname to $tbname$date;rename table new to $tbname;truncate table $tbname;"
```

Comment: `$?` includes the state of the previously executed command. `$?` will be `0` if the SQL query was successful. Otherwhise, it will be `1`.

Answer (score 3):

you can check the exit code of mysql

demo:

```
~$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh
mysql -e"select 1"
ret=$?
echo "correct syntax: $ret"

mysql -e"select bad syntax"
ret=$?
echo "bad syntax: $ret"

if [ "$ret" = "0" ]; then
    echo "mysql executed ok"
else
    echo "mysql executed failed"
fi




~$ sh a.sh
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
correct syntax: 0
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'bad' in 'field list'
bad syntax 1
mysql executed failed
```